# DropdownListFor user Roles not populating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, roles, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to make a website where the user will have the option to register with a role. For some reason my dropdownlist is not populating. I have the following error. I have the login page and the register page in one page. And i am starting the website by calling the login page.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Role'.

Can anyone give me a clue why this is happening? Here is my code.

View page:

```
<div class="form-group mb-0">
                    @Html.Label("Role", new { @class = "col-sm-6 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Role, ViewBag.RoleList as List<SelectListItem>)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Controller:

```
 // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login( string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            return View();               
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout   
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true   
            ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {

                //After he signs in check his role and you will redirect him to the correct page
                //User.IsInRole use this(returns true or false)
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }

        }
```

Model :

```
 public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a role")]

        public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterViewModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a role")]

        public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have RoleList as a property on both models, yet you assign your select list to ViewBag - is there a reason you're doing that?

Comment: Debug your `ViewBag.RoleList ` variable and check what the key value pair is. The current key you are trying to get doesn't exist. Should try `model => model.Id`

Comment: @TiesonT. Not any specific reason i found an example online and i followed the steps.

Comment: @LinkedListT checked it. ive got the following error "CS0411: The type arguments for method 'SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. "

Comment: As mentioned earlier, debug and check the key-value pair of your `ViewBag.RoleList` then use the corresponding key in your `dropdownlist`

Comment: @LinkedListT sorry for the question i am a kinda new to asp.net but where should i put my breakpoint?

Comment: in your `login` GET method. Specifically            `ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "Name");` check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019